# What is a good design for expanding opcodes?

Tags: computer-architecture

Are there any tutorials on YouTube or good text tutorials on designing expanding opcodes? I always make mistakes on switching from one line to another and "counting" in binary. I pretty much know how to design them, but I don't really understand it and I make so many mistakes. I also don't have any examples to go by and check my answer.
Here's one example of what kind of designing and exercises I need:
Design 1 three-address instruction, 10 two-address instr, 7 one-address instr and 4 zero-address instr. The addresses are 8 bits each and 2 bits for an instruction (style: 00 xx yy zz)

So I went about doing designing it like this:

```
00 xx yy zz

00 00 yy zz
00 01 yy zz
00 10 yy zz
00 11 yy zz
10 00 yy zz
10 01 yy zz
10 10 yy zz
10 11 yy zz
11 00 yy zz
11 01 yy zz

11 10 00 zz
11 10 01 zz
11 10 10 zz
11 10 11 zz
11 11 00 zz
11 11 01 zz
11 11 10 zz

11 11 11 00
11 11 11 01 
11 11 11 10 
11 11 11 11
```

and the last one is all 1s so I guess it's correct. Maybe if there are no tutorials on YouTube, someone can simplify it or explain it here in text?

Comment: What do you mean by "designing expanding opcodes"?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is simply the problem of mapping a set of possible values (i.e., possible instructions) to some bit encoding.

You haven't specified whether all instruction encodings need to have the same length.

- If they can have different lengths, usually you'll want them to form a [prefix-free encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) (no encoded value is a prefix of any other).
- If all instruction encodings must have the same length,any mapping that gives different instructions different encodings is acceptable.

Your solution doesn't look OK to me.  `00 00 yy zz` is a prefix of `00 xx yy zz` if `xx`, `yy`, and `zz` are the addresses `00000000`.

Editorial comment: the exercise is a bit boring and trivial, and doesn't involve much in the way of deep concepts.  It's just a matter of "bit-packing".

Comment: There is some info on opcodes here:
http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~prabakar/cda4101/Common/notes/lecture22.html

http://www.personal.kent.edu/~aguercio/CS35101Slides/Tanenbaum/CA_Ch05_PartII.pdf

I'm preparing myself for an exam and the questions are quite trivial. And all the info I have about the question is that the addresses are the same, they are 8 bits long and have 2 sets (?) of addresses each (like 00 xx yy zz, not xxx yyy zzz). And then they say design the addresses in 1 three-address instructions, 7 two address instructions etc.

Comment: Some of the examples of the exams are already answered and they are answered like I did mine in the first post. Here's an example: http://i.imgur.com/IUOjRBP.png 
I just translated the Macedonian text
All of the examples end in 11 11 11 11...

Answer (score 2):

When designing a variable-length opcode you are doing the equivalent of [*Huffman coding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).  In the case that the opcodes have known, independent, and identically distributed probabilities then Huffman coding gives you the optimal symbol-by-symbol prefix code.

As @DW points out, what you need here is a [*prefix code*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code).  A code such that no opcode is the prefix of any other opcode.  Prefix codes are equivalent to binary trees where each leaf of the tree is an opcode.  So take any tree with the correct number of leaves, label each leaf with an operation, then the opcode for each operation is the path from the root to the leaf.  (Where "going left" in the path is a "0" and "going right" in the path is a "1".)

If you know the probabilities of the operations you are encoding then you can create a Huffman tree by keeping a [*priority queue*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) of nodes, where the "priority" here is the probability of the node.  You start with the queue filled with the leaves (operations), each with its probability.  On each iteration you pull out the two lowest priority nodes, create a parent for them, make the two low-priority nodes the children of the parent, and give the parent the probability that is the sum of the children.  Then you insert the parent back into the priority queue and repeat until you have only one node left.

Alternatively, if you don't know the probabilities, but you are trying to design an encoding where operations with many operands have shorter opcodes and operations with fewer operands have longer opcodes, then you are trying to design an unbalanced tree with a specific number of leaves at each level.  Start with the operations that need the fewest operands and build upwards.

In your example, you know you need 4 operations with zero operands, so start by creating a balanced tree with 4 leaves, 2 intermediate nodes and one root.  Now you need 7 operations with one operand (plus the 4 operations with zero operands) so you build a balanced tree with 8 leaves, attach your "zero operand" tree to one of the leaves, and label the other 7 leaves with your 7 one-operand operations.

Next you need 10 two-operand operations.  Just repeat the process of tree building from the bottom up, and eventually you will be finished.  Then just read off the opcodes for each operation by following the path from root to the leaf corresponding to the operation.

Comment: Nice answer, but I am a tiny bit disappointed that there was no mention of facilitating decoding via regularity in placement of components (particularly the most timing critical ones, e.g., register names) and quick discovery of instruction length (mostly for superscalar implementations). Of course, the HW/exam questions of this type are not interested in such details (like planning for extension [when binary compatibility is important] or even, in a VLE, of providing [canonical] nops of different sizes for convenient packing).